# JS tasks keeps running all the time

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I have defined this Gulp configuration:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen();

    gulp.watch('src/AppBundle/Resources/public/css/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/**/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('src/AppBundle/Resources/public/css/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/AppBundle/Resources/public/css/min'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/Sencamer/Resources/public/js/**/*.js') //select all javascript files under js/ and any subdirectory
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('sencamer.min.js')) //the name of the resulting file
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/min'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Any time I execute the gulp file using `gulp default` from console I get this output:

```
[22:44:40] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/project.dev/gulpfile.js
[22:44:40] Starting 'css'...
[22:44:40] Finished 'css' after 7.86 ms
[22:44:40] Starting 'js'...
[22:44:40] Starting 'watch'...
[22:44:40] Finished 'watch' after 22 ms
[22:44:41] Starting 'css'...
[22:44:41] Finished 'css' after 1.16 ms
[22:44:44] Finished 'js' after 3.6 s
[22:44:44] Starting 'default'...
[22:44:44] Finished 'default' after 3.58 μs
[22:44:44] Starting 'js'...
[22:44:50] Finished 'js' after 6.1 s
[22:44:50] Starting 'js'...
[22:45:01] Finished 'js' after 10 s
[22:45:01] Starting 'js'...
[22:45:14] Finished 'js' after 14 s
[22:45:14] Starting 'js'...
[22:45:31] Finished 'js' after 17 s
[22:45:32] Starting 'js'...
[22:45:51] Finished 'js' after 19 s
[22:45:51] Starting 'js'...
[22:46:14] Finished 'js' after 23 s
[22:46:14] Starting 'js'...
[22:46:42] Finished 'js' after 28 s
[22:46:42] Starting 'js'...
```

But why `js` task keeps executing all the time? What I'm doing wrong here?

**Update**

I've made some changes in this line:

```
gulp.watch('src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*.js', ['js'])
```

But now I got this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:189:18)
    at js_error (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:197:11)
    at parse_error (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:299:9)
    at /var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:511:36
    at Object.next_token [as input] (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:536:36)
    at next (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:643:25)
    at subscripts (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1307:13)
    at subscripts (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1288:20)
    at expr_atom (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1165:20)
    at maybe_unary (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1328:19)
    at expr_ops (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1363:24)
    at maybe_conditional (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1368:20)
    at maybe_assign (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1392:20)
    at expression (/var/www/html/project.dev/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1411:20)
```

Why? Still `watch` looking inside `js/min` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are watching your **src/AppBundle/Resources/public/...** directory and inside the task writing into it. So after change you are triggering task again.

Output files into directory where files are not being watched.

Comment: I've made some changes to my configuration, but still not working, can you please point me on the right direction? Is my first time using Gulp

Comment: Instead of 'src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js/min' use 'src/AppBundle/Resources/public/js-min', because you are watching all files inside js directory and all subirectories.